# why does mat-sort not working on my mat-table

Tags: angular-material-7

I'm using multiple mat-tables on one page. I need a mat-sort for one table.

when I debug the code response get with results but matSort not working

```
 <table #transactions class="transactions-table" mat-table [dataSource]="trassactionDataSource" matSort>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Transaction ID </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.transaction_id}} </td>
     </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="product_name">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.listing_title}} </td>
     </ng-container>

.....

     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">         </tr>
</table>
```

'

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'product_name', ...];

@ViewChild(MatSort)private sort: MatSort;

 ngOnInit() {
       this.userService.getDashboardData().subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.code == 401) {
        this.authService.logout(true);
      } else {

           this.trassactionDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.result.transactions);

           var that = this;
           setTimeout(function () {
               that.trassactionDataSource.sort = that.sort;
           }, 500);
      }
}[enter image description here][1]
```

I don't get any console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading this. I figure it out. `matColumnDef = response result`

ex:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Transaction ID </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.transaction_id}} </td>
     </ng-container>
```

change in to

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="transaction_id">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Transaction ID </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.transaction_id}} </td>
     </ng-container>
```